# Running a stored procedure from Java using Statement Execute?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures

My Java code goes

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String storedProc = "exec stored_proc(" + someVariable + ")";
statement.execute(storedProc);
```

But Java throws an SQLSyntaxException. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

In your current approach you can use:

```
String storedProc = "{call stored_proc(" + someVariable + ")}";
```

Note that I have used `call` instead of `exec`, and I have surrounded query with curly braces.

But to avoid `sql injection` you can use parametrised query like:

```
String storedProc="{call stored_proc(?)}";
PreparedStatement pstmt=connection.prepareStatement(storedProc);
pstmt.setString(1,someVariable);
pstmt.execute(storedProc);
```

Comment: how can i change this 'EXEC spGetCustomerDetails   123455789'

Comment: @R.Anandan I didn't get your point, please ask a separate question or explain your question in detail here.